# Set Calendar Week to Start With Sunday

Tags: calendars, nokia-lumia-730

I have a Lumia 730, and I am unable to configure it so that the week starts with sunday. How can I configure this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The latest update for the Calender app allows you to set the first day of week, as well as the first week of the year. Check the Store for the update.

For more information, see [Windows Central](http://www.windowscentral.com/calendar-windows-phone-81-update-brings-new-agenda-view-more).

Comment: @Indrek whats wrong with the answer i have posted?

Comment: Nothing wrong per se, it's just that your answer focused on the setting for first week of year, when the question was about the first day of week. So rather than posting a second, essentially duplicate answer, I decided to try and improve yours. If you're unhappy with my edit, you're always free to revert it, but do note that [collaborative editing is a major part of this site](http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/help/editing).

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is a known problem and there is an outstanding feature request for this.

In other words, you can't!

Comment: Is there is any special application for this in windows store?

Comment: @Naveen Not as far as I know. It is something Microsoft need to address and I agree is very annoying.